# Create sequences for each client

Tags: php, postgresql, sequence-sql

I am working to improve an old PHP project.

For that project we have a Client table in a postgresql database.

Each client have two sequences in the database.

Before, everytime we had a new client, DEV team had to insert the client in the client table and create two sequences.

```
INSERT INTO client (...) VALUES (...);
CREATE SEQUENCE client_n_seq1;
CREATE SEQUENCE client_n_seq2;
```

Now I want that DEV team don't insert clients in the database, I want to provide a tool to make the "business people" insert them.

The first requirement is, the PHP code should not create the sequence.

What I was thinking about is to create a database function triggered every time after insert a client in the client table.

The first sequence is used to numerate the receipts generated for that client.
The second sequence is a identifier of a file, that should be imported in a third party software .

**My question is**: What is your opinion? there is another way to provide the same functionality (have two "sequences", and increment the value one by one) without creating those sequences in the database?

Comment: "another way to provide the same functionality" - we have no idea about the functionality.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev let´s see after my update you can understand better my problem.

Comment: If creating two sequences per client, you might hit some DB limits if your app grows too much. What you can do instead is write your own sequence logic. For example, store those two numbers (last receipt id, last file id) in clients table and increment when needed. Of course, this requires a bit of effort to protect from race conditions and such. Especially so if you use an ORM.